# Add Column in Grid view according to SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-3.5

I am using this query:

```
select EmployeeId, receptionist_name, date_of_sale,
  count(date_of_sale) 
from FrontOffice 
group By EmployeeId, receptionist_name, date_of_sale 
order by date_of_sale
```

for filling the grid view. But I can bound the `EmployeeId`, `receptionist_name`, `date_of_sale`, so can you tell me how can I bound the 4th column in grid view and how to fill the grid view.

**UPDATE:** Here is the code I am using:

```
<Columns> 
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="date_of_sale" /> 
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employe Id" DataField="EmployeeId" /> 
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Receiptist Name" DataField="receptionist_name" /> 
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No. of Prospectus Sale"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Label ID="salecount" runat="server" 
          Text='<%# Eval("SaleCount") %>'></asp:Label> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField> 
</Columns>
```

Comment: <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="date_of_sale" />
               <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employe Id" DataField="EmployeeId" />
               <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Receiptist Name" DataField="receptionist_name" />
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No. of Prospectus Sale">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="salecount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SaleCount") %>'></asp:Label>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>

Comment: i don know how to add the html code in question?

Comment: Ok I will add it for you but please edit it and add other details.

Comment: Please add the code you are using to populate these data from the database as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the followings:

1. Change your query to this:

   `select EmployeeId, receptionist_name, date_of_sale,
   count(date_of_sale) as Total from FrontOffice  group By EmployeeId,
   receptionist_name, date_of_sale  order by date_of_sale`
2. Change your Gridview code to this:

   `Replace Eval("SaleCount")  to Eval("Total")`

Answer (score 1):

instead of changing whole code Just alias the column like `count(date_of_sale) As SaleCount`

```
<Colums>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="date_of_sale" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employe Id" DataField="EmployeeId" /> 
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Receiptist Name" DataField="receptionist_name" /> 
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="No. of Prospectus Sale" DataField="SaleCount" />
</Columns>
```

Comment: I guess you didn't change the SQL script to count(date_of_sale) As SaleCount. Please change it and try.